Dropdown menu inside a navigation bar doesn't work as expected in Apple touchscreen devices and some browsers
HERE is the code I copied from w3schools.com to have a clickeable dropdown menu inside a navigation bar.
It works okay in any desktop OS (I tried MacOS and Ubuntu) and any browser (I tried Safari and Firefox) but the issue comes with Apple touchscreen devices.
Tap on a dropdown menu expands okay the options but it is not possible to collapse it unless tapping on its options or other navigation bar items.
No way tapping on any other place of the screen to collapse the dropdown menu.
I tried with an iPhone 11 Pro Max and a iPad mini 4 latest iOS and Safari, Opera and Chrome browsers.
Also tested in 2 Android cellphones and they worked okay as expected.
Is there something I am missing in the code?


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;  
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn, .dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body style="background-color:white;">

<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction()">Dropdown
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
  </div> 
</div>

<h3>Dropdown Menu inside a Navigation Bar</h3>
<p>Click on the "Dropdown" link to see the dropdown menu.</p>

<script>
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(e) {
  if (!e.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
  var myDropdown = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
    if (myDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
      myDropdown.classList.remove('show');
    }
  }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>




What is the expected way of collapsing the dropdown when not activating one of the dropdown links or other navigation links? Are you saying tapping "Dropdown" again doesn't close it on the Apple touchscreen devices? Why can't you tap anywhere else on the screen?

For example, if the user is not interested in the dropdown options he starts scrolling the presented page. Doing that implies touching the screen, then the dropdown menu should collapse. In Android devices that is what happens but in iOS the dropdown options remain despite the user scrolls up or down or taps anywhere in the screen. The only way to hide them is to tap other nav bar items or one of the options presented in the dropdown menu. This is wired.

The snippet and the jsFiddle both work for me in Safari on my iPhone. Tap the menu, it drops down, tap again, it folds up.

Thanks for the test you've done. Some witchcraft in my house with iOS. It doesn't make sense that happens with different devices and internet browsers. I was thinking something about caches, but they spread to other devices/browsers? Also found that Refresh doesn't always work as a full refresh unless after some time (hours). This is a matter of other forum (off topic)
